# In Matlab, how to store a recorded audio data into small buffers while recording?

Tags: matlab, real-time, microphone

I am using `record` function to record audio data. It has to be done this way because I have multiple microphones to be recorded simultaneously and the `record` function can provide "multithreaded" recording.

```
n = 10; % length
record(recObj, n);
```

When I run this, I know recording is happening in the background. However, I want to access each small buffers that the `record` function uses to pull in the data. I need them so I can do real-time processing on multiple microphone signals. How should I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `recObj` is an `audiorecorder` object. You can call `recObj.getaudiodata`. This requests the whole data, if this is to mouch data copy the `audiorecorder.m` and create your own getaudiodata which allows to set the `InputStream` to a starting position before reading.